# Render many to many relationship JSON in Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have the next models

```
defmodule App.User do
  use App.Web, :model
  alias App.User

  schema "users" do  
    field :name, :string
    has_many :roles_users, App.RolesUser
    has_many :roles, through: [:roles_users, :role]
    timestamps
  end
end 

defmodule App.Role do
  use App.Web, :model

  schema "roles" do
    has_many :roles_users, App.RolesUser
    has_many :users, through: [:roles_users, :user]
    field :name, :string
    timestamps
  end

end

defmodule App.RolesUser do
  use App.Web, :model

  schema "roles_users" do
    belongs_to :role, App.Role
    belongs_to :user, App.User
    timestamps
  end
end
```

Is for a many to many relationship. My controller to show is

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  users = Repo.all(User)
        |> Repo.preload(:roles)

  render(conn, "index.json", users: users)
end
```

In the view I have

```
def render("index.json", %{users: users}) do
  %{users: render_many(users, App.UserView, "user.json")}
end

def render("show.json", %{user: user}) do
  %{user: render_one(user, App.UserView, "user.json")}
end

def render("user.json", %{user: user}) do
  %{id: user.id,
    name: user.name,
    roles: user.roles
 }
```

When I sent the GET request I got this error

```
unable to encode value: {nil, "roles"}
```

I know that could be because `user.roles` need to be formatted in some way to decode the JSON, but I have not any clue about this. I have tried in the form

```
def render("user.json", %{user: user}) do
  %{id: user.id,
    name: user.name,
    roles: render_many(roles, App.UserView, "roles.json")
 }
```

But is not working.

What is the best way to render many to many relationships in view?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using [render_many/4](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render_many/4) is correct.

If you wish to define the "role.json" render function in the same module you can do:

```
def render("user.json", %{user: user}) do
  %{
    id: user.id,
    name: user.name,
    roles: render_many(user.roles, __MODULE__, "role.json", as: :role)
  }
end

def render("role.json", %{role: role}) do
  %{
    id: role.id
    ... 
  }
end
```

Notice that we pass `as: :role` to the render_many function. This is because the assigns (the `%{role: role}`) part is inferred from the view name. In this case it is the `UserView` so it would be `%{user: user}` by default.

If you define a `RoleView` module then you can just move the `def render("role.json")` function to your new `RoleView` and call `render_many` without the `as` option:

```
...
roles: render_many(user.roles, MyApp.RoleView, "role.json")
...
```

Another option that may be preferable for you is to derive a protocol in your model:

```
defmodule App.Role do
  use App.Web, :model
  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:id, :name]}

  schema "roles" do
    has_many :roles_users, App.RolesUser
    has_many :users, through: [:roles_users, :user]
    field :name, :string
    timestamps
  end
```

Personally I feel this couples your model to your view, so I prefer to use the first option.

Comment: It works! Thank you! I got a role as "roles": [
        {
          "name": "Administrador",
          "id": 2
        }
      ],

Comment: Great answer, and helpful. One thing though: shouldn't the:
    roles: render_many(user.roles, __MODULE__, "roles.json", as: :role)
actually be:
    roles: render_many(user.roles, __MODULE__, "role.json", as: :role)
to properly match with the defined render function taking "role.json" as an argument?

Comment: @Nik Great spot. I've updated the answer. Just so you know, you can use backticks (\`Like this\`) so that `__MODULE__` doesn't display as __MODULE__.