# Limit fields of JSON response

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using the PhoenixFramework and the library [Poison](https://github.com/devinus/poison). 
Current I'm working on an REST API. Now I need to encode the model `Book` in two different ways.

1. In a list of all books with only base informations (`GET /books`)
2. In a detailed view with all informations (`GET /book/1`)

**`GET /books`**

```
{
  "books": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Book one"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Book two"
    },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

**`GET /books/1`**

```
{
  "book": {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Book one",
     "description": "This is book one.",
     "author": "Max Mustermann",
    // ...
  }
}
```

**Encoder of `Book`**

```
defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: MyProject.Book do

  @attributes [:id, :name, :description, :author]

  def encode(project, _options) do
    project
    |> Map.take(@attributes)
    |> Poison.encode!
  end
end
```

**Snippet controller**

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  books = Repo.all(Book)
  json(conn, %{books: books})
end
```

How to limit the fields? I search for a option like `:only` or `:exclude`.
Has anyone experience with this problem?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [render_many/4](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render_many/4) and [render_one/4](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render_one/4):

```
defmodule MyApp.BookView do

  def render("index.json", %{books: books}) do
    render_many(books, __MODULE__, "book.json")
  end

  def render("show.json", %{book: book}) do
    render_one(book, __MODULE__, "full_book.json")
  end

  def render("book.json", %{book: book}) do
    %{
      id: book.id,
      name: book.name
    }
  end


  def render("full_book.json", %{book: book}) do
    %{
      id: book.id,
      name: book.name,
      description: description,
      author: book.author
      ...
    }
  end
end
```

Please note that the name in assigns (2nd argument of render) is determined by the module. See [Render many to many relationship JSON in Phoenix Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750899/render-many-to-many-relationship-json-in-phoenix-framework/34751835#34751835) for an example of using a different name.

You can then call this from your controller using:

```
render(conn, "index.json", books: Repo.all(Book))

render(conn, "show.json", book: Repo.get(Book, 1))
```