# Elixir map changing structure as passed around

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm missing something basic with my phoenix code

This is in my controller

```
  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    user = Repo.get!(User, id)

    query =
        from c in Card,
            where: c.user_id == 1,
            select: {c.id, c.inserted_at, c.estimate_name, c.product}
    estimates = Repo.all(query)

    render(conn, "show.json", %{user: user, estimates: estimates})
    # render(conn, "show.json", user: user)
  end
```

And in my view

```
  # def render("show.json", %{user: user}) do
  def render("show.json", %{user: user, estimates: estimates}) do
    %{data: render_one(%{user: user, estimates: estimates}, Api.UserView, "user.json") }
    # %{data: render_one(user, Api.UserView, "user.json")}

    #  ** New code since original post **
    # %{data: render("user.json", %{user: user, estimates: estimates})}
  end

  def render("user.json", %{user: user, estimates: estimates}) do
  # def render("user.json", %{user: user}) do
    %{id: user.id,
      firstname: user.firstname,
      lastname: user.lastname,
      email: user.email,
      customerId: user.customerId,
      estimates: render("estimates.json", estimates)}  # **Line with last error**
  end

  def render("estimates.json", [head | _estimates]) do
    #   Enum.map(estimates, fn estimate -> render(mapper estimate, MosaicApi.UserView, "summaryEstimate.json") } end)
    # render(mapper(head), MosaicApi.UserView, "summaryEstimate.json")
    render("summaryEstimate.json", mapper(head))

  end

  # ** I'm fear I have added unnecessary complexity here **
  def mapper({id, date, name, product}) do
      %{id: id,
        creation_date: date,
        estimate_name: name,
        product: product}
  end

  def render("summaryEstimate.json", estimate) do
    %{id: estimate.id,
      estimate_name: estimate.estimate_name,
      product: estimate.product}
  end
```

But I get an error, which seems to be because my data has morphed from `%{user: ..., estimates: [...]}` to `%{user: %{estimates:[...], user: %{...}}`.

How did that happen, and how can I prevent it?

```
Could not render "user.json" for MosaicApi.UserView, please define a matching clause for render/2 or define a template at "web/templates/user". No templates were compiled for this module.

Assigns:

%{user: %{estimates: [{1, #Ecto.DateTime<2016-04-26T12:01:34Z>, "cards for annabelle", "Business Cards"}, ...], user: %Api.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>, customerId: "CUST", email: "foo@foo.be", firstname: "fname 1", id: 1, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-04-26T11:46:21Z>, jobs: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :jobs is not loaded>, lastname: "lname 1", updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-04-26T11:46:21Z>}}, view_module: Api.UserView, view_template: "user.json"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [render_one/4](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render_one/4) and [render_many/4](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render_many/4) functions inflect the assigns name from the view. I explain this in [Render many to many relationship JSON in Phoenix Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750899/render-many-to-many-relationship-json-in-phoenix-framework/34751835#34751835)

So what happens when you call:

```
render_one(%{user: user, estimates: estimates}, Api.UserView, "user.json")
```

Is that `render` is called with the following arguments:

```
render("user.json", %{user: %{user: %{...}, estimates: [...]})
```

You can change the name of assigns using `as`:

```
render_one(%{user: user, estimates: estimates}, Api.UserView, "user.json", as: :data)
```

Which will call render with:

```
render("user.json", %{data: %{user: %{...}, estimates: [...]})
```

You can match this with:

```
def render("user.json", %{data: %{user: user, estimates: estimates}}) do
```

---

You can avoid this by calling `render` directly instead of using `render_one`:

```
render("user.json", %{user: user, estimates: estimates})
```

Another option is to use a data structure that nests the estimates inside of the user struct. Perhaps by adding a virtual attribute to your schema.

**EDIT**

```
  def render("show.json", %{user: user, estimates: estimates}) do
    %{data: render("user.json", %{user: user, estimates: estimates})}
  end

  def render("user.json", %{user: user, estimates: estimates}) do
    %{id: user.id,
      ...
      estimates: render_many(estimates, __MODULE__, "estimates.json", estimates. as: estimate)}
  end

  def render("estimates.json", %{estimate: {id, _date, name, product}}) do
    %{id: id,
      estimate_name: name,
      product: product}
  end
```

Comment: That made a big difference, but I'm now getting `argument error
(stdlib) :maps.from_list([{1, #Ec...`. I've added some more code. I thought my query was delivering a list and that I could pattern match against that, but not sure that that is in fact the case

Comment: Looks like you went off track a little, check my edit.

Comment: THANKS!! Looks like you had a typo as it eventually needed `estimates: render_many(estimates, __MODULE__, "estimates.json", as: :estimate)}`

Answer (score 3):

> How did that happen, and how can I prevent it?

That's because `Phoenix.View.render_one` wrapped your assigns to be in a key inflected from the view's name.

[From its docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render_one/4):

> The following:
>
> ```
> render_one user, UserView, "show.html"
> ```
>
> is roughly equivalent to:
>
> ```
> if user != nil do
>   render(UserView, "show.html", user: user)
> end
> ```
>
> The underlying user is passed to the view and template as `:user`, which is inflected from the view name.

You should just call `render/2` directly:

```
def render("show.json", %{user: user, estimates: estimates}) do
  %{data: render("user.json", %{user: user, estimates: estimates}}
end
```

Comment: That made a big difference, but I'm now getting `argument error
(stdlib) :maps.from_list([{1, #Ec...`. I've added some more code. I thought my query was delivering a list and that I could pattern match against that, but not sure that that is in fact the case